# In a resource file, how can I reference the background colour of a button in the current theme?

Tags: android, android-theme

In a resource XML file, I know I can use

```
<solid android:color="?android:colorBackground"/>
```

to reference the current theme's background colour, but how do I reference the background colour that buttons use in the current theme?

Comment: thats relative, but did you try something like ?android:id/button_id ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `@android:drawable/btn_default_holo_light`

Comment: I was specifically looking for a current theme reference with ?android: rather than @android: